# How to avoid website url appending problem in wp site?

Tags: menus

On localhost when I opens my site (Ex: **http://example.com**) and when I select any navigation menu then the url of my selected navigation menu appends the previous url. some what  like this (**http://example.com#http://localhost/example.com/?page_id=2**) but I just want  (**example.com/?page_id=2**). I damn sure the problem should be in index.php but I am unable to solve it. Anyone can help me to resolve it?

Can anyone answer it?

Comment: Please post the code from `index.php` that generates the links.

Comment: Sounds like you might have messed up your database. Have you migrated lately?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off all plugins and switch to Twenty Thirteen to see if the problem goes away. If yes: figure out which theme and or plugin is causing the problem and re-post a more specific question. If no: re-install WP and follow set-up procedure. Back up data first if working live.

Comment: Actually I am integrating one template into wordpress3.5. And for this I am using my own developed custom theme. I guess the problem should be in header.php or index.php only.

Comment: And I don't have any plugins activated nor missed the database. But still I am facing the problem. Please suggest me anyone.

Comment: Does the problem still exist when running Twenty Thirteen?